# Facebook API difference between 'page_video_views' and 'total_video_views'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The facebook API provides video stats via 'Page Video Views' and 'Video Insighs'.

'Page Video Views' has the metric page_video_views (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/insights#videoviews).

'Video Insighs' has the metric total_video_views
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/).

Apart from the 'period', are these 2 metrics fundamentally referring to the same stats?

I also know about post_video_views, but this one seems a bit more straightforward in understanding.

EDIT: based on further reading of ‘Page Video Views’, the metrics here seem to be the combined stats of all the videos on a page. This metric doesn’t break the stats down into individual videos. So it just gives an overall sense of how people are engaging with all the videos on the Page.

Possible conclusion -> 'Page Video Views' give overall stats of all video combined that can be broken down into daily. Video Insights give stats for individual videos but only for lifetime.

Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos can be "crossposted", meaning the same video can be used on multiple different pages.

https://www.facebook.com/help/678485232304895:

> Crossposting is a way to use videos across multiple Pages.

The `page_video_views` metric is for videos that played directly on your page. That's for *all* the videos on your page. `post_video_views` would be for one specific post, containing a specific video.

`total_video_views` is a metric for an individual video. That includes *all* views, across all pages where the video might have been used.

Comment: Thanks for the response CBroe. At this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/
it says that video_insights is to 'Get aggregated insight metrics for a videos on a Page'.

Based on what I am seeing on my project, total_video_views is only for views on the page. It doesn't return the stats for views across all pages. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Is it really a cross-posted video? Not the same video, but uploaded separately in two different places?

Comment: Yes it is a cross-posted video. If I hover over the 'views' in the bottom right corner (example https://www.facebook.com/watch?v=261820065741627), I can see the views stating that it is from different posts. I think this means that the video has been cross-posted.

Current problems: from article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/insights, crossposted Video will have its own unique video-id for each Page it was posted to.

The challenge is to get the complete view stats for a cross-posted video. I don't think it is possible via the Facebook API at this moment.